# Android Java method invocation

Tags: java, android

```
Cursor c = getContent().query(Phones.CONTENT.URI, null, null, null, null);
```

How do you read this line of code? First, are these two method calls within a method call?  I thought when you have a method call within a method call the first method call is an argument inside the parentheses of the second method call.  Am I reading this wrong?

And second what exactly does this line of code do?

Answer (score 0):

`getContent()` will get some object instance, and then it uses that to call `query(...)`.

It is doing something similar to this...

```
Content content = getContent();
Cursor c = content.query(...);
```

So what this code is doing is getting the results from the content query (via `query`) and puts it into a `Cursor` object, which can be used to access the results.

Answer (score 0):

It's calling one method, and then using the result as the target of another method.

Note that this has nothing to do with Android... it's perfectly normal Java.

As a simpler example:

```
String x = "hello there";
int y = x.substring(2, 4).length();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, it's hard to know exactly what this does without knowing the context. A generic answer is that it queries some content provider for some information, while passing no information (the 4 nulls).

As for how it's read, let me try.

**Cursor c**

This declares a variable (c) of type Cursor

**getContent()**

This calls the getContent() method *of the executing class or it's super class* which returns, in my best guess, a ContentResolver (or something similar) object.

**query(....)**

Invokes the "query" method on the returned value (most likely a ContentResolver) of the getContent() method, while passing some values to the method.

**Phones.CONTENT_URI**

A static/constant variable that defines the URI of the Phone ContentProvider.